# How can I remove excessive parentheses in MySQL view source

Tags: mysql, dbeaver

I am adding views that join many table to my MySQL 5.7 database.  When I try to view the source of the view after saving it I see that MySQL has added lots of parenthesis.  How can I easily remove these to make my code more readable.  I use DBeaver to do my editing.  This is a snippet of what it does to my query that joins 12 tables.

```
from
    (
        (
            (
                (
                    (
                        (
                            (
                                (
                                    (
                                        (
                                            (
                                                (
                                                    (
                                                        `flight` `f`
                                                    join `flight_legs` `fl` on
                                                        (
                                                            (
                                                                `fl`.`flight_id` = `f`.`id`
                                                            )
                                                        )
                                                    )
```

Comment: I've no knowledge of dbeaver but if it's like any other SQL IDE I would junk the gui and just edit your SQL directly.

Comment: Views aren't stored as text, they're stored as an internal representation of the parsed query. When you use `SHOW VIEW`, it uses a simple algorithm to convert this back to text, and adds lots of parentheses.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TLDR: You almost certainly can't.

Under the covers dbeaver is using MySQL's [SHOW CREATE VIEW](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/show-create-view.html) statement as seen [here in the source of dbeaver's MySQL plugin](https://github.com/dbeaver/dbeaver/blob/a3703f7b356a904dac0d8e662e23f7912ec5626e/plugins/org.jkiss.dbeaver.ext.mysql/src/org/jkiss/dbeaver/ext/mysql/model/MySQLView.java#L214) which returns MySQL's internal representation of the view.  According to the linked docs:

> No matter how you write out a view definition, MySQL always stores it the same way, in a canonical form.

This is what is being returned to dbeaver when it queries for the view definition.  It looks like dbeaver apply some formatting to the string after the fact, and that formatter does pull in preferences, but I expect that is more about indentation or syntax highlighting than changing the actual text. It would take more digging to be sure, but the answer is almost certainly that you can't.

Comment: I accept the fact that I can't and will have to deal with the parens each time make changes.  So does anybody know of a formatter or tool that will strip unnecessary parenthesis out?

Comment: What I ended up doing was so simple it is almost embarrassing.  I replace '(' with '' and ')' with '' and then ran the DBeaver format SQL tool and it looks great.  I should have explained that the view source is just straight joins with no where clause so no need for parens.